Proper value for dns search in /etc/resolv.conf and how to set it
On RockyLinux 9.x I noticed if my server hostname is mysite.com then inside /etc/resolv.conf by default I would have
search com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1

Isn't search com a security problem ? For example if I run ping home (while having search com) it resolves to some Google user server (35.237.212.184).
I am thinking that any code on my server that has references to short names like home can be compromised, like triggering commands or certain packages installing some updates from random remote ips thinking they are local. Or allow certain IPs to access services on the server thinking they are local/home.
Only way to remove the com and specify my own value is to set system hostname to server1.mysite.com:
hostnamectl set-hostname server1.mysite.com

then /etc/resolv.conf would become:
search mysite.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 1.1.1.1


Is there a security problem to have search com there ? For the reasons above.
What is the proper value to have in search area of /etc/resolv.conf ?
What is the proper way to set this default value ?
Can I fully remove that ? If so, how ?
Why does RedHat ask for subscription to access this exact same information ? 

Manually I was not able to fully remove default search value, but only able to append values by this command:
nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.dns-search "myserver.mysite.com"

Thank you.

Purpose of the search Option in /etc/resolv.conf
The search option in /etc/resolv.conf is used to define a list of domains that the system appends to unqualified hostnames when performing DNS queries. This is particularly useful in environments where short, unqualified hostnames (like server1 or home) are commonly used, allowing the system to automatically resolve these names within the specified domain or domains. For instance, if you have search mysite.com and you ping server1, the system will attempt to resolve server1.mysite.com automatically.
Security risks
Having search com in /etc/resolv.conf can lead to unintended DNS queries to external domains, posing minimal security risks. For example, resolving an unqualified hostname like home could inadvertently resolve to home.com, potentially connecting to an unexpected IP address. Although these risks are generally low, especially if you don't rely on unqualified hostnames, it's advisable to mitigate them by setting a specific, trusted domain in the search option, such as mysite.com. Alternatively, you can set your hostname to a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) like server1.mysite.com, which will update the search option to your domain. If you prefer to eliminate this setting entirely, you can use NetworkManager to remove the search value, ensuring that your server only resolves fully qualified domain names.
nmcli
To Modify:
nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.dns-search "mysite.com"

To remove it entirely (Yes, that's fine):
nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.dns-search ""

Why does RedHat ask for subscription to access
I believe Red Hat requires a subscription for access to detailed documentation, support, and knowledge base articles as a way to fund the development and support of the distribution.

nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.dns-search "" still results in search com. It acts like it would only remove additional searches, but not that default one. Do you know a way to fully remove it ? If I do nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.dns-search "mysite.com" then it becomes search mysite.com com, best solution I found is to change my system hostname to something.mysite.com, then it would become search mysite.com.

In that case, I recommend disabling changes to the resolv.conf file through NetworkManager entirely. As suggested on this AskUbuntu thread (https://askubuntu.com/questions/623940/network-manager-how-to-stop-nm-updating-etc-resolv-conf), simply add the following lines to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf dns=none and
rc-manager=unmanaged. After that, manually edit the /etc/resolv.conf file and remove the search example.com entry.
